# varchar is missing on pgadmin4 UI

Tags: postgresql, macos, pgadmin

I am very new on Postgresql. I have installed pgadmin4 on my Mac OS X. I try to create a very basic table with a column which has type `varchar` but it doesn't seem to have ti on the list of the UI.

Am I missing something?

[image: pgadmin4 UI]

Comment: It might use the real name `character varying`

Answer (score 31, accepted):

According to [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/datatype-character.html) both `character varying` and `varchar` is correct.

Select `character varying` as the data type in pgadmin 4.

Comment: This only allows creation of character arrays, which doesn't permit you to use strings, only explicit arrays of characters.

Comment: Make sure you select `character varying` and not `character varying[]` which is a different kettle of fish. Only with `character varying` can you UPDATE/INSERT simple `'string'` values.